# How to make a Health-Check curl call in Circle-Ci

Tags: docker, curl, graphql, circleci, health-check

I am trying to make a health check during my circleci workflow to see if the app compiles successfully. Despite the app building on circleci, `curl` is never able to find to the localhost port.

I have tried this locally on my machine and it works great.

Below is my workflow job:

```
  health-check:
    docker:
      - image: image_name
    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker
      - restore_cache:
          key: image-cache-ci-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_KEY }}
      - run:
          name: start 
          command: |
            docker load < image.tar
            docker run -d graphql-ci:$CIRCLE_KEY "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js"
            docker run graphql-ci:$CIRCLE_KEY curl http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health
```

The app successfully compiles. However, the second line always returns the following:

```
12354314532412342: Loading layer  1.803MB/1.803MB
Loaded image: graphql-ci:234523451325424
34523453153145235345234523452345234
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused

Exited with code exit status 7
```

I have also tried to use `wait-on` - `wait-on http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health && curl http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health`

I have also placed the curl called in a separate run step after the build one

```
      - run:
          name: check that the server is up
          command: |
            docker load < image.tar
            docker run graphql-ci:$CIRCLE_KEY curl http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health
```

I have also tried to use `docker exec` but then it just tells me that it cannot find my docker container (and then specifies the docker container image hash).

If I remove the detach flag `-d` then it will show that it successfully started.

```
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
```

The default PORT set is 4000, I add a flag to the docker run command to include `--env PORT=4000` to just confirm it. Didn't affect anything but I know that it is running.

I also gave `pm2` a try for the server since then the same terminal will be available by default. This will run but makes no difference.

Really just want to curl a sever I know is loaded in one circleci job.

Entrypoint
`CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]`

EDIT:

I got closer to getting a successful result.

scripts

```
    "curl": "if [[ $(curl -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health) == 200 ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi",
    "ci": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js",
    "health": "start-server-and-test ci http-get://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health 'npm run curl'",
```

curl returns `1` if successful (returns 200) and `0` otherwise.
I also installed a package called `start-server-and-test` which starts the server, waits for it to finish then run the final script. It is normally used for cypress but works here too.

This was the result

```
> @bespokemetrics/graphql@ curl /usr/src/app
 
> if [[ $(curl -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://localhost:3000/.well-known/apollo/server-health) == 200 ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi

 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
 
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 
100    17  100    17    0     0   8500      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8500
 
1 // this was the returned
 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 143
npm ERR! package_name: `./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 143
```

Why does it return an ERR despite succeeding?

Comment: Have you try to expose the port 4000?

Comment: Do these exact steps with docker run work on your local or does docker exec work on your local? Also, could you post what is the CMD or ENTRYPOINT instruction used for this Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I also created an npm script to container all of the code needed to trigger the test on 1 line.

```
      - run:
          name: Start and Curl Server
          command: |
            docker load < image.tar
            docker run graphql-ci:$CIRCLE_SHA1 npm run health
```

```
    "curl": "if [[ $(curl -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health) == 200 ]]; then echo 'Success'; pkill node; else echo 'Failure'; fi"
    
    "ci": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js"
    
    "health": "start-server-and-test ci http-get://localhost:4000/.well-known/apollo/server-health 'npm run curl'"
```

I installed a package called `start-server-and-test` which allows you to start your server, wait for it to build, then run whatever command you want all on 1 line.

My curl command only returns the status code, if 200 then return a success message and kill the node process. That was the err that was returned after the success earlier because it wasn't closed properly.